# Extract backup (file-parts .tgz) in folder

Tags: linux, backup

I was have Debain (vps), earlier he does make backups and upload them on Google Drive.

Now i need restore data, from last backup file. Structure backup file:

```
root@local:~# cd /var/tmp/2019-06-30.zip/    <-- zip backup
<-- unpacked zip to folder /var/tmp/2019-06-30/
root@local:/var/tmp/2019-06-30/# ls
2019-06-30.www-root.info         
2019-06-30.www-root.tgz  
/.backup.info                <-- tgz contains file .backup.info      
F2019-06-30.www-root.tgz.part1
F2019-06-30.www-root.tgz.part2   
...
- From 1 to 19 of the same *.tgz.part*
...
F2019-06-30.www-root.tgz.part19
```

Can I combine this, in order to unpack everything together from the archives? 
In parts, my 7z cant this make, how i can make this with tgz consistently?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the file parts with `cat` and pipe the result to `tar` to extract everything:

```
cat F2019-06-30.www-root.tgz.part* | tar xz
```

Or you can do this in two steps with a combined tgz:

```
cat F2019-06-30.www-root.tgz.part* > F2019-06-30.www-root.tgz
tar xfz F2019-06-30.www-root.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `-d` flag of `unzip`
Create temp folder `mkdir tmp_name` then
`unzip your_zip_file.zip -d tmp_name`

Comment: Notice that the OP has already unzipped the zip file and are now asking how to unpack the split archive.

Comment: My mistake I will update my ans. with proper solution. Thanks